# How to start gluon mobile PositionService using start() method with different Parameters like accuracy, time interval etc

Tags: gluon-mobile

Currently I am using the gluon mobile PositionService to detect user current location. But I want to configure the PositionService  with diffrent settings using
Parameters API. But when  I use start(Parameters parameters) I am getting redirected to  location settings in android application.
Please tell me what is a best way to configure and start this service using paramters.

```java
         public void initialize() {
             try {
                setupLocationService();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error setting up location service", t);
            }
        }


        private void setupLocationService() {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Register position service ");
        Services.get(PositionService.class).ifPresent(ps -> {
            // If I uncomment following line the application presenter is not displayed
            // Instead I see the Location menu in anroid settings page when user has to manulaly enable the location
            //ps.start(new Parameters(Parameters.Accuracy.LOW, LocationSynchronizer.ACCEPTABLE_TIMEFRAME, LocationSynchronizer.ACCEPTABLE_ACCURACY, true));
            ps.positionProperty().addListener(e -> {
                Position position = ps.getPosition();
                if (position != null) {
                    // sync location using rest API
                    locationSynchronizer.syncronizeLocations(position);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "getting redirected"? Can you edit your question and post what you have tried already?

Comment: Can you add also your Android manifest?